# Angular images and span not showing

Tags: angular

Hello Im adding some images an using a tooltip animation on hover, I have used the same setup in react and vanilla js. Im currently using Angular 2 and for some reason my spans nor images will show up, I know im using the correct path because if i put the image outside the container span it shows the image.

```
div class="row">
      <div>
        <div class="text">
          <span class="tooltip" data-tooltip="sometext">
            <img alt="icon" class="img-thumbnail" src='assets/images/img.png'/>
          </span>
        </div>
```

css

```
tooltip {
  position: relative;
  padding: 5px 12px;
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 15px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  color: #FFF;
  font-family: 'Kanit', sans-serif;

}

.tooltip:before,
.tooltip:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.tooltip:before {
  border-width: 10px 8px 0 8px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: grey transparent transparent transparent;
  top: -130px;
  left: 75px;
  transform: translateY(20px);
}

.tooltip:after {
  content: attr(data-tooltip);
  background: grey;
  width: 160px;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 300;
  top: -190px;
  left: -10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-align: center;
  transform: translateY(20px);
}

.tooltip:hover::before,
.tooltip:hover::after {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(-2px);
}

@keyframes shake {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(2deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(-3deg);
  }
  70% {
    transform: rotate(3deg);
  }

  100% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}

.skillz:hover {
  animation: shake 500ms ease-in-out forwards;
}
```

Comment: Could you show .text and .tooltip css?

Comment: span not a block element display . put your image inside a div not a span

Comment: I have added the css and tried using a div instead of span but the div didnt work.

Comment: line 1 of your css....is it a typo? Are you missing a dot for class? This seems to apply to an element.

Comment: Unable to reproduce issue [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pdqrfd?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, I have bootstrap installed and I couldnt use the tooltip class.